# What are those "garbage" 16 bytes at the beginning of an unencrypted EncryptedData tag from an encrypted ws-security SOAP message? (WCF)

Tags: iphone, wcf, encryption, soap, ws-security

I'm inspecting a WCF request message in order to implement part of the WS-Security standard to have iPhone <-> WCF intercommunication (I'm using certificate security over basicHttpBinding).
After reading the standard [xmlenc-core](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlenc-core/) I could decrypt both the SignedInfo and the Body tags, but I see 16 bytes at the beginning of both unencrypted tags from which I have no idea.
I create a sample application according to the standard in order to send request from the iPhone to a self hosted WCF but it continues responding "An error occurred when verifying security for the message".
The only thing I don't know how to implement are those 16 bytes, does anybody knows what to use on those 16 bytes?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Triple-DES and AES the cipher-text is prefixed by the IV. So when decrypting, you should use the first 16 bytes of the value as the IV and then perform the AES-CBC decryption on the remaining bytes. My guess is that you have forgotten this and thus are decrypting the IV also (which will yield garbage).

Comment: Thanks for the response! It's weird though, because every other time I've used the Crypto API on the iPhone none of those bytes appeared :S. Thanks anyway!